# what is the minimum age of criminal responsibility in India ? and can abeted child criminals be held accountable under the juvenile justice act?

Tags: india, juvenile-law

https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/2079?sam_handle=123456789/1362

the Juvenile justice act is the main act that deals with juveniles

the "definitions" section in the act defines juveniles as any person under 18 , does that mean any child that commits a crime is applicable to be tried under the act ?

Also regarding abetment. Can a child who was instigated or enticed or encouraged to commit a crime be held responsible under this act ? Fo3 example there were(2016 or 2017 after the 2015 juvenile justice act and before the 2019 amendment to POCSO act though it has retroactive effect from what I've read so far) various posts/answers on Quora(a popular Q&A website with a majority Indian userbase) encouraging children under 18 to have sex or offering dating and other sexual tips on Quora . can those children that follow the direct advice   be held accountable under this act and POCSO act , what about the advice givers ? would this count as abetment ? for example some of the users (who may or may not be adults) enticing and encouraging a child to have suggestive or sexual profile pictures(with one of them having such profile picture according to my memory before the bans) or texts for them in the comments (this seems like a textbook case for section 13 of the pocso act)

the pocso act  > (https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/2079?sam_handle=123456789/1362)

This act doesn't have any provision about if consent of a child is relevant to offences in the act and there doesn't seem to be any law in India regarding the age of consent for non penetrative sexual activities.

and with regards to the consent defence , IPC(the substantial criminal law) section 91 states that the consent of any child under age 12 is invalid.  which brings the question of what about the consent of children under 18 and above 12 ?